# sql server result table to picture

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
Select 
  QID,
  (point), 
  count (0) as t
from WebSurveyResponse
group by QID,point
order by qid ,point
```

[image]

I want to like this

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `PIVOT` or else you can use case statement and make columns for point1,point2,point3.. and the group them by `QID` and take `MAX` value of each column.

```
SELECT QID,
MAX(Point1) AS Point1,
MAX(Point2) AS Point2,
MAX(Point3) AS Point3,
MAX(Point4) AS Point4
FROM(
        SELECT QID,
               CASE WHEN Point=1 THEN t ELSE 0 END as Point1,
               CASE WHEN Point=2 THEN t ELSE 0 END as Point2,
               CASE WHEN Point=3 THEN t ELSE 0 END as Point3,
               CASE WHEN Point=4 THEN t ELSE 0 END as Point4
        FROM WebSurveyResponse
                                )
GROUP BY QID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT to get the resultant structure

```
Select QID, [1] as [point 1], [2] as [point 2], [3] as [point 3], [4] as [point 4] from 
(
Select 
  QID,
  (point), 
  count (0) as t
from WebSurveyResponse
group by QID,point
) src
PIVOT
(
Max(t) for point in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)p
```

Also as suggested in comments you can use the count as aggregation in the PIVOT like so

```
Select QID, [1] as [point 1], [2] as [point 2], [3] as [point 3], [4] as [point 4] from 
(
Select 
  QID,
  point
from WebSurveyResponse
) src
PIVOT
(
Count(point) for point in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)p
```

Comment: I think you could use `Count` function in pivot table and remove `group, order` in `src table`